# What is meant by "higher-level protocol" in the RTMP specification?

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, audio-streaming, rtmp, rtmps

Looking at the [RTMP specification](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/rtmp/pdf/rtmp_specification_1.0.pdf), in section 5 (RTMP Chunk Stream) it says:

> RTMP Chunk Stream includes its own in-band protocol control messages,
>    and also offers a mechanism for the higher-level protocol to embed
>    user control messages.

What is meant by "higher-level protocol"?

It also specifies: "While RTMP Chunk Stream was designed to work with the Real Time Messaging Protocol (Section 6), it can handle any protocol that sends a stream of messages". Aren't the RTMP Chunk Stream and Real Time Messaging Protocol the same?

Answer (score 0):

When RTMP was first released, the Chunk Stream transport worked over sockets or HTTP (though I don't think the HTTP tunneling was ever documented, open source implementations exist).  Later Adobe released RTMFP for peer-to-peer communication over UDP.  In both these cases, RTMP is a higher level protocol independent of how the RTMP messages are encoded.

For more info, see https://rtmp.veriskope.com/docs/overview/